# What is the meaning of this conditional sum notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

## Short version

What is the meaning of this sum notation?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{r_1 + \dots + r_p = r}^{} (\dots)
\end{equation}
I understand that $r = 0, 1, \dots, \infty$, but what about $r_1, \dots, r_p$? What values should I assign to $r_1, \dots, r_p$?

## Long version (with context)

I am looking for a closed-loop expression of the expectation of the square root of a quadratic form $Q(X) = X' A X$ with $X \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $A \succeq 0$.

The answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144893/what-is-the-expected-norm-mathbb-e-lvert-x-rvert-for-a-multivariate-normal) mentions the book by Mathai & Provost, "Quadratic forms in Random Variables", that in Theorem 3.2b.5 reports the following equation for $\mathbb{E}[{Q^{h'}}]$ with $h' \in (0, 1)$. In my case $h' = h = 1/2$.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[{Q^{h'}}] 
    &= \alpha^h \exp\left(-\sum_{j = 1}^{p} b_j^2 / 2 \right) 
    \Biggl\{ \sum_{j = 1}^{p} b_j^2 \lambda_j \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{r_1 + \dots + r_p = r}^{} \frac{\left(\frac{b_1^2}{2}\right)^{r_1} \cdots \left(\frac{b_p^2}{2}\right)^{r_p}}{r_1 ! \cdots r_p !} 
    \frac{\Gamma(\nu_1 + \dots + \nu_p + r - h)}{\Gamma(\nu_1 + \dots + \nu_p + r)} 
    \nonumber \\
    &
    F_D(h; \nu_1 + r_1, \dots, \nu_p + r_p; \nu_1 + \dots + \nu_p + r; 1 - 2 \alpha \lambda_1, \dots, 1 - 2 \alpha \lambda_p)
    \nonumber \\
    &
    + 
    \sum_{j = 1}^{p} \lambda_j \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{r_1 + \dots + r_p = r}^{} \frac{\left(\frac{b_1^2}{2}\right)^{r_1} \cdots \left(\frac{b_p^2}{2}\right)^{r_p}}{r_1 ! \cdots r_p !} 
    \frac{\Gamma(\eta_1 + \dots + \eta_p + r - h)}{\Gamma(\eta_1 + \dots + \eta_p + r)}
    \nonumber \\
    &
    F_D(h; \eta_1 + r_1, \dots, \eta_p + r_p; \eta_1 + \dots + \eta_p + r; 1 - 2 \alpha \lambda_1, \dots, 1 - 2 \alpha \lambda_p)
    \Biggr\}
\end{align}
where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_p$ are the eigenvalues of $A \Sigma$ and $P$ is the orthogonal matrix of the eigenvectors of $A \Sigma$, that is
\begin{align}
    [b_1,\, \dots,\, b_p]^T
    &= P^T \Sigma^{-1/2} \mu
    \\
    \text{diag}\left( [\lambda_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda_p]^T \right) &= P^T \Sigma^{1/2} A \Sigma^{1/2} P
    \\
    P P^T &= I
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    \nu_i &= \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } i \neq j \\
        \frac{1}{2} + 2 & \text{if } i = j
    \end{cases}
    \\
    \eta_i &= \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } i \neq j \\
        \frac{1}{2} + 1 & \text{if } i = j
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
$\alpha$ is an arbitrary parameter such that $\alpha > 0$ and $|1 - 2 \alpha \lambda_j| < 1$ for $j = 1, \dots, p$.
Finally, $F_D$ is a Lauricella function.

Everything is clear to me except for the sums
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{r_1 + \dots + r_p = r}^{} (\dots)
\end{equation}
that appear twice in the expression.
I guess that the index $r$ is a sequence $r = 0, 1, \dots, \infty$.
However, how am I supposed to pick the values of $r_1, \dots, r_p$?
Can I pick them arbitrarily as a set of positive integers such that $r_1 + \dots + r_p = r$?
Yet, the fact that there are two sums makes me think that I should pick multiple sets of $r_1, \dots, r_p$ for each $r$.

Comment: It usually means all tuples of non-negative integers $r_1,\dots,r_p$ that add up to $r.$ But if $p$ is not an externally-defined value, it could mean positive $r_i$ that add up to $p.$ It really depends on the context. But here, $p$ is a fixed value, and not allowed to vary inside the sum.

Comment: A typical example would be expanding $$\prod_{i=1}^p\frac{1}{1-x_iy}$$ and seeking out the coefficient of $y^r.$ Then it would be $$\sum_{r_1+\cdots+r_p=r} x_1^{r_1}\cdots x_p^{r_p}$$ and the full power series would be: $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty y^r\sum_{r_1+\cdots+r_p=r} x_1^{r_1}\cdots x_p^{r_p}$$

Comment: OK, so, for example, if $p = 2$, when $r = 0$, $(r_1, r_2) \in \{(0, 0)\}$, when $r = 1$, $(r_1, r_2) \in \{(0, 1), (1, 0)\}$, and when $r = 2$, $(r_1, r_2) \in \{(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)\}$, and so on?